# How do I set a decay period for structures in ARK? (PVP raid prevention)

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

( Excuse me if I do not use the proper gamer terminologies )

This is my first time being the Admin of my own server, and I would like to reproduce one common behavior of much PVP servers that I seen...

When playing in some PVP servers I seen that the structures/houses cannot be raided by other players until a specific time period has past (mostly in days or weeks), and it seems this decay period depends on the time that the owner of the structure is offline, I mean if the owner of the structures connects to the server, then the decay period dissapear, I'm right about this?.

I hope you could understand what I mean. When a player is near a structure of other player, a label is shown informing about the remaining decay period to wait until the structure become raideable (or "spoileable"). I like this thing because it seems a method for prevent raids and also for help removing trash/abandoned structures from the server to avoid a wipe due to too much structures in the map.

My question is: I can do this by modifying a parameter in the ini files, or I need a specific MOD for this?. And additionally but optionally: which is the suggested (balanced) time period value that I should set for a PVP server?.

Comment: I know you can set up offline raid protection natively, but not sure how to make it expire. Maybe take a look at http://ark.gamepedia.com/Server_Configuration